Is it possible to create a Grid in Genexus Smart Device with collapsible elements?
I would like to create a grid in Genexus with collapsible elements.
Or, alternatively, even if they were not collapsible I would just need to group them by category
What I want is something like this
CustomerA
  Object1
  Object2
CustomerB
  Object3
  Object4

Possibly with the possibility of collapsing individual customer sections. I've tried a grid with Customers containing components, but I can't put components into a grid. Are there alternatives?
I'm working with Genexus 17U10

Yes, what you can do is create a FreeStyle Grid, and within it, place the CustomerName and another nested FreeStyle Grid that contains the objects.
And you can set the inner grid to be collapsed or not.
FreeStyle Grid Customer
   FreeStyle Grid Objects + -


Sorry, I wrote it in the title, but then I forgot to rewrite it in the text. This is in Smart Device, I don't have Free Style Grids in Android

If you´re using WWSmartDevices, you could add an order by CustomerId or the attribute you want to group by and put the property "Break by" on true:

This should generate mini titles on the Grid groupped by Customer.
I don´t know if it's posible to collapse this mini titles cause i don´t know the name they have in desing:

